# Create PDF with AngularJS from array object?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, pdf

Say, I have an array object:

```
$scope.data =
            [
                {name: 'Tom', city: 'Paris', profession: 'Student'},
                {name: 'Lilly', city: 'London', profession: 'Artist'},
                {name: 'Adam', city: 'Berlin', profession: 'Singer'}
            ];
```

How can I create a PDF file from this that displays a simple table that looks like this:

```
+-------+--------+------------+
| name  |  city  | profession |
+-------+--------+------------+
| Tom   | Paris  | Student    |
| Lilly | London | Artist     |
| Adam  | Berlin | Singer     |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: This data can be export as csv file, which it will be a table in excel. Google `ng-csv`.

Answer (score 4):

Try any of the 3 options

- j[sPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)
- [PDFkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)
- Rasterization Example from [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/examples/)